Google cloud function to zapier error (400)
Image 1. zapier Settings Window
Image 2. Error Contents
I'm working on converting the answers returned from Chat GPT into HTML and then turning them into Latex strings.
To this end, I'm trying to process it after sending a webhook from Zapier to Google Cloud, but I keep returning the HTTP Status code:400 error.
What is the problem, or what should I look at to figure out what the problem is?

Google Cloud Function File Settings

main py
import functions_framework
from markdown2 import markdown
import pypandoc

@functions_framework.http
def convert_text(request):
    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    if request_json and "text" in request_json:
        text = request_json["text"]
        
        # Convert text to HTML
        html_content = markdown(text)
        
        # Convert HTML to LaTeX
        try:
            latex_content = pypandoc.convert_text(html_content, 'latex', format='html')
        except RuntimeError as e:
            return {'error': f'Conversion error: {str(e)}'}, 500
        
        response = {
            'html': html_content,
            'latex': latex_content
        }
        
        return response, 200
    else:
        return {'error': 'Invalid request: missing text field'}, 400

ruquirements.txt
functions-framework==3.0.0
markdown2==2.4.0
pypandoc==1.6.3


maybe first check what you get in request_json - maybe there are some information which can explain why it doesn't have text. Maybe it sends it as request_json['data']['text'] instead of request_json['text']
